# Order location by oldest date without returning record for each date stamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this sub query that needs to return the SUM(qty) for each rack and bin ordering the rack/bin by the earliest date first (ASC). Every time I use the date field to sort the data, it returns a record for every date. I added the date field in the SELECT statement for reference. How would I go about doing this??

```
SELECT InventoryItems_1.ItemID,
       SUM(ISNULL(InventoryItems_1.QtyToStock, 0)) AS InvQty,
       InventoryItems_1.Rack,
       InventoryItems_1.Bin,
       InventoryItems_1.LocationID,
       MIN(InventoryItems_1.Date),
       Locations_1.LocationCode,
       Locations_1.DescriptionMed
FROM dbo.InventoryItems AS InventoryItems_1
     INNER JOIN dbo.Locations AS Locations_1 ON InventoryItems_1.LocationID = Locations_1.LocationID
WHERE(InventoryItems_1.OwnerDetailID IS NULL)
GROUP BY InventoryItems_1.ItemID,
         InventoryItems_1.LocationID,
         InventoryItems_1.Rack,
         InventoryItems_1.Bin,
         InventoryItems_1.Date,
         Locations_1.LocationCode,
         Locations_1.DescriptionMed
HAVING InventoryItems_1.ItemID = 10308
ORDER BY InventoryItems_1.LocationID,
         InventoryItems_1.Date,
         InventoryItems_1.Rack,
         InventoryItems_1.Bin;
```

This is my result:

```
ID      Qty     Rack    Bin     Loc     Date                LocID
10308   35      21      02-Z    7   2018-10-22 14:48:33.000     WI  
10308   52.5    21      02-Z    7   2018-10-23 08:18:44.000     WI  
10308   87.5    18      01-Z    7   2018-10-23 12:19:09.000     WI  
10308   87.5    23      01-B    7   2018-10-24 11:02:35.000     WI  
10308   35      19      09-Z    7   2018-12-06 14:24:14.000     WI  
10308   22.5    19      09-Z    7   2018-12-06 16:52:26.000     WI  
10308   30      19      09-Z    7   2018-12-07 07:55:59.000     WI  
10308   55      19      09-Z    7   2018-12-07 08:54:55.000     WI  
10308   32.5    19      09-Z    7   2018-12-07 09:47:19.000     WI  
10308   87.5    19      03-C    7   2018-12-07 11:36:20.000     WI  
10308   72.5    19      10-Z    7   2018-12-07 13:17:03.000     WI  
10308   15      19      10-Z    7   2018-12-07 14:30:38.000     WI  
10308   32.5    18      07-A    7   2018-12-17 13:39:39.000     WI  
10308   12.5    19      03-A    7   2018-12-17 14:48:57.000     WI  
10308   42.5    19      03-A    7   2018-12-18 08:07:42.000     WI  
10308   87.5    19      11-Z    7   2018-12-18 10:11:23.000     WI  
10308   87.5    19      06-B    7   2018-12-18 12:08:17.000     WI  
10308   87.5    18      03-Z    7   2018-12-26 13:40:34.000     WI  
10308   55      21      05-Z    7   2018-12-26 14:48:58.000     WI  
10308   32.5    21      05-Z    7   2018-12-27 07:49:27.000     WI  
10308   87.5    19      01-B    7   2018-12-27 09:55:59.000     WI  
10308   8       18      07-A    7   2018-12-28 09:40:11.000     WI  
10308   0.5     18      08-B    7   2018-12-28 09:40:11.000     WI  
10308   75.5                    9   2018-11-27 11:55:17.000     NJ  
10308   7                       10  2018-10-24 08:28:26.000     TX  
10308   2.5                     10  2018-11-02 10:07:27.000     TX  
10308   12.5                    10  2018-11-02 14:36:57.000     TX  
10308   10.5                    10  2018-11-27 13:56:11.000     TX
```

This is what I want it to look like sorted by the oldest inventory date first.

```
ItemID  InvQty  Rack    Bin     Loc LocCode 
10308   87.5    18      01-Z    7   WI  
10308   87.5    18      03-Z    7   WI  
10308   40.5    18      07-A    7   WI  
10308   0.5     18      08-B    7   WI  
10308   87.5    19      01-B    7   WI  
10308   55      19      03-A    7   WI  
10308   87.5    19      03-C    7   WI  
10308   87.5    19      06-B    7   WI  
10308   175     19      09-Z    7   WI  
10308   87.5    19      10-Z    7   WI  
10308   87.5    19      11-Z    7   WI  
10308   87.5    21      02-Z    7   WI  
10308   87.5    21      05-Z    7   WI  
10308   87.5    23      01-B    7   WI  
10308   75.5                    9   NJ  
10308   32.5                    10  TX
```

Comment: You can't order by a column that you don't return--besides, ordering by date here without showing it wouldn't be understood by the user or anyone looking at this data. What's the goal here?

Comment: I think you can remove your  inventoryitems_1.Date from your group by clause

Comment: @ scsimon: This query is part of a pick list. I want the user to pick the oldest inventory from the top. Otherwise the rack/bin order is random.

Comment: @ pascal sanchez: you have to have the field in a group by or aggregate function if it is in the order by.

Comment: You should use ROW_NUMBER in a cte to allow you to select only the "first" one in each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grouping by the `InventoryItems_1.Date` field, which is why separate rows are coming out for each date. Changing your query to NOT group by this, and naming your minimum date field would allow you to generate the correct output. Also, if you want to limit your report to only one ID, put that in the WHERE clause, not the HAVING clause. This will filter the records before you perform your GROUP BY calculations etc, speeding your output.

```
SELECT InventoryItems_1.ItemID,
       SUM(ISNULL(InventoryItems_1.QtyToStock, 0)) AS InvQty,
       InventoryItems_1.Rack,
       InventoryItems_1.Bin,
       InventoryItems_1.LocationID,
       MIN(InventoryItems_1.Date) As MinDate,
       Locations_1.LocationCode,
       Locations_1.DescriptionMed
FROM dbo.InventoryItems AS InventoryItems_1
INNER JOIN dbo.Locations AS Locations_1 
    ON InventoryItems_1.LocationID = Locations_1.LocationID
WHERE InventoryItems_1.OwnerDetailID IS NULL
    AND InventoryItems_1.ItemID = 10308

GROUP BY InventoryItems_1.ItemID,
         InventoryItems_1.LocationID,
         InventoryItems_1.Rack,
         InventoryItems_1.Bin,
         Locations_1.LocationCode,
         Locations_1.DescriptionMed
-- HAVING InventoryItems_1.ItemID = 10308
ORDER BY InventoryItems_1.LocationID,
         MIN(InventoryItems_1.Date),
         InventoryItems_1.Rack,
         InventoryItems_1.Bin;
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks! I see what I did wrong now! The ItemID filter was only for this example, otherwise it would have returned thousands of records.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
SELECT 
    InventoryItems_1.ItemID
,   ISNULL(InventoryItems_1.QtyToStock, 0) AS InvQty
,   InventoryItems_1.Rack
,   InventoryItems_1.Bin
,   InventoryItems_1.LocationID
,   InventoryItems_1.Date
,   Locations_1.LocationCode
,   Locations_1.DescriptionMed
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID, Bin, LocationID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) RN 
    FROM dbo.InventoryItems 
) InventoryItems_1
INNER JOIN dbo.Locations AS Locations_1 ON InventoryItems_1.LocationID = Locations_1.LocationID
WHERE
    InventoryItems_1.RN = 1
AND InventoryItems_1.OwnerDetailID IS NULL
AND InventoryItems_1.ItemID = 10308
ORDER BY InventoryItems_1.LocationID,
         InventoryItems_1.Rack,
         InventoryItems_1.Bin;
```